# Incrementing/Decrementing using JPanel and JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I have been trying to solve this for quite some time now and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PushCounterPanelMath extends JPanel
{
    private int count;
    private JButton inc;
    private JButton dec;
    private JLabel label;

    public PushCounterPanelMath()
    {
        count = 0;
        inc = new JButton("Increment");
        dec = new JButton("Decrement");
        label = new JLabel();
        inc.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        dec.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        add(inc);
        add(dec);
        add(label);
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            
            count++;
            label.setText("Value: " + count);
            if(event.equals(dec))
                count--;
            label.setText("Value "  + count);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to increment and decrement value using two buttons, but for some reason it only increments it whether I press "Increment" or Decrement"
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

event.equals(dec) is never going to be true; an ActionEvent is never equals to a JButton. But you can use event.getSource();

```
        if(event.getSource().equals(dec))
            count--;
        else count++;
        label.setText("Value "  + count);
```